# In media player seek bar won't progress along with the playing media in android studio

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have been working on a media player and tried to integrate a seek bar, I used a Bind service to code the MediaPlayer functions and called those function in my Activity using the reference of that bind service, I used a Handler to assist the runnable, However, my seekBar is unable to track the progress of playing media.

The code for tracking SeekBar is as follows:-

```
Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
seekUpdate();
    }
};
public void seekUpdate(){
    seekBar.setProgress(service.currentPosition());
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
}
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        service.seekTo(progress);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
```

And the Code from my Bind Service Class(Where MediaPlayer functions have been integrated) is as follows:-

```
package com.daman.mediaplayer;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BindMusicService extends Service {
    String songToPlay,songPath;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    IBinder ibRef = new MyBinder();
    PlayerActivity play;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        songToPlay = intent.getStringExtra("keySong");
        songPath=intent.getStringExtra("songpath");
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songPath);
            //mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(url));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ibRef;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
    public void playMusic(){
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void pauseMusic(){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void stopMusic(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    public int currentPosition(){
       return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    public int getDuration(){
       return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }
    public  void seekTo(int position){
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
    }
    class MyBinder extends Binder{
        BindMusicService getServiceReference(){

                return BindMusicService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

When i play and pause the media the error that pops in android monitor is :-

```
04-03 21:08:28.873 23092-23092/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x00000000 from pkg=
                                     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1359)
                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:812)
                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
                                         at android.widget.RemoteViews$TextViewDrawableAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1502)
                                         at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2805)
                                         at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
                                         at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1373)
                                         at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2805)
                                         at android.widget.RemoteViews.reapply(RemoteViews.java:2795)
                                         at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:2175)
                                         at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateNotification(BaseStatusBar.java:2044)
                                         at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$6$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:513)
                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of the issue?